# Density of different liquids in manometer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

[image]
According to diagram, liquid X and liquid Y have the same pressure on mercury, but how can I know which of them will be denser, liquid X is denser than liquid Y or reverse argument?

Comment: Hint: how do you calculate the weight of the X & Y columns using their densities?

Comment: I am asking because the question in the textbook does not include any further information, I think that equal level of mercury on both sides indicate that liquid X and Y have the same pressre on mercury, but I can't understand which one of them is more denser

Comment: You didn't answer my question about density. But yes, the pressure is the same on both sides. What formula do you know that connects pressure and force? Remember, weight is a force.

Comment: Pressure = force(weight) /area

Comment: Correct. And density = mass / volume. Now can you figure it out?

Comment: I know that density directly proportional with pressure, as liquid X has high volume so it has low density and therefore low pressure

Comment: But this happens when mass of liquid X and Y are the same

Comment: Yes. Columns X & Y have the same pressure, and the same cross-section area, so they have the same weight. But column X has greater volume, so liquid X must have lower density than liquid Y.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Ramiki, the pressure at the bottom of a column of liquid is given by $P=\rho g h$.  This should be enough of a hint for you to qualitatively determine the density relationship between the fluids in the legs of the manometer.